# React Native Android get device's ratio

Tags: android, android-camera, react-native, expo

I'm using Camera that comes from `expo` package and I'm having trouble with camera view distortion. My phone has `2:1` ratio, which is non-standard.

When I use `getSupportedRatiosAsync` method of the camera, I get all kinds of ratios like `1:1`, `2:1`, `4:3`, `16:9`, however only `2:1` looks good.

How can I select a ratio that fits device's natural resolution? Is there a way, to access device's preferred ratio? Or is there any hack around it, like always selecting `16:9` and having the camera component add black margins, where the actual device's ratio is not fitting the `16:9`?

EDIT:

My phone resolution is `2196x1080`, therefore correct ratio should be `2:1`. But I'm unable to come up with a function that would compute `2196x1080`=>`2:1`, since `(2 * 1080) !== 2196`

Is there any way how to infer best possible ratio even for such stupid resolutions?

Comment: "My phone resolution is 2196x1080, therefore correct ratio should be 2:1." - The camera ratio is not necessarily the same size as the device screen ratio. Take a look at your native camera app - does it have a status bar? Does it have space for the button used to take the picture? If yes to either of these, then that explains the discepency between your phone display resolution and your camera resolution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Samsung S9, the screen aspect ratio of `18.5:9` is very close to `2:1`. And if you don't [hide the navigation bar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation), the area devoted to your camera preview is probably even closer to the suported `2:1`.

But if you want this to work on all devices with their different screen aspect ratios and different supported camera aspect ratios, you must crop the preview to your window, see e.g. https://github.com/waitopiggu/rn-camera-android-cropping-test.

As for choosing the best camera aspect ratio, you are right that exact match may not be acvailable; let's find the one that is closest to what we want:

```
const wantedRatio = height/width
var bestRatio = 0;
var bestRatioError = 100000;
for (i in ratios) {
    const r = ratios[i].split(":")
    if (abs(wantedRatio - r[0]/r[1]) < bestRatioError) {
        bestRatioError = abs(wantedRatio - r[0]/r[1])
        bestRatio = ratios[i]
    }
}

this.setState({
    bestRatio
})
```

Comment: I'm sure the idea is good, but the code doesn't work. For example `r` is an Array and you're trying to subtract it from `wantedRatio` which is a number. Could you please fix it?

Comment: Oops, that's what happens wihen trying to copy/paste and clean up in the same time ;)